# How to set R environment variables on Linux

Tags: linux, environment-variables, r

I call an R script from PHP and it works well. 
I just call it using this function

```
shell_exec("Rscript play.r");
```

To do that I had to set environment variables in Windows
to the R executable be recognized by the OS.

Well now I am trying to do the same for Linux. I have the same error that I had on Windows before setting environment variables:

```
Rscript:not found 127
```

I think the Linux operating system is not finding the path to the R "executable" when I call it from PHP.

I think that I must to set the environment variables to R on Linux
but I don't know how to do that.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not necessarily need to set environmental variables. Simply call `Rscript` by its full path:

```
shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/Rscript ...");
```

Of course, change the path to wherever it really is. You can check from a shell by running `which Rscript`.

If you really want to change the PATH for PHP, you should check [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10764335/435093).